# How to have UIScrollView animate off screen when dragged

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

So I have a `UIViewController` and I have a `UIScrollView` inside of it, which has some UI elements.

I want the user to be able to drag the `UIScrollView` up and down, but when it drags past a certain threshold, I want it to animate off the screen. There needs to be some springiness to it though. I tried using `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:` but couldn't seem to get it right. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In scroll view delegate method `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` observe `scrollView.contentOffset.y` and trigger animation when it reaches expected y position.

for example:

```
CGFloat yTranslation = -200.f; // Value you want to shift

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
     scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, yTranslation);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     // code after completion
}];
```